# Difference between using ng-model and ng-control in angular2?

Tags: angular

```
 <form role="form" #form="form" (ng-submit)="submit(form.value)">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" ng-control="name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" [(ng-model)]="email">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
```

What is the diff b/w using ng-model and ng-control? When to use each of them?

Comment: There is no `ng-submit`, `ng-control`, `ng-model` in Angular2 since about beta.49. They should be `ngSubmit`, `ngControl`, `ngModel`.

Comment: yes. correct. still what is the diff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngControl`, `ngModel` and `ngFormControl` are selectors for [`NgControlStatus`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgControlStatus-directive.html) directive, so there's no difference between them...

> **NgControlStatus is** Directive automatically applied to Angular forms that sets CSS classes based on control status (valid/invalid/dirty/etc).

[`NgFormControl`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgFormControl-directive.html) is directive that binds input field in the template to the [`Control`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/Control-class.html) class that is used to programmatically create form fields.

> **NgFormControl** Binds an existing Control to a DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Controls are responsible to get hints about the state of the form or a specific input (valid, pristine, touched, ...). It's commonly used to display validation errors if any. Here is a sample:

```
<div
     [ngClass]="{'has-error':!inputControl.valid && !state.control.pending,'form-group':label,'form-group-sm':label}">
  <label *ngIf="label" for="for"
     class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 control-label">My input</label>

  <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8"
       [ngClass]="{'col-sm-8': label, 'col-md-8': label}">
    <input [(ngModel)]="myInput" [ngFormControl]="inputControl"/>
    <span *ngIf="!inputControl.valid" class="help-block text-danger">
      <div *ngIf="state?.errors?.required">The field is required</div>
      (...)
      <div *ngIf="state?.errors?.invalidZip">The zip code format isn't correct</div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also detect changes on an input leveraging the `valueChanges` attribute of control, as described below:

```
this.inputControl.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
  console.log('value updated - new value = '+data);
});
```

Since it's an observable you can leverage operators to create an aynchronous processing chain. For example to synchronize a list based on an input:

```
inputControl.valueChanges.debounceTime(500).flatMap(
  val => {
    return this.service.searchPlaces(val);
  }).subscribe((data) => {
    this.places = data;
  });
```

On the other side, `ngModel` allows to bound an input to a property of the component using two-way binding. If the property is updated by code, the input value will updated and if the input is updated by user, the property will be updated.

---

As pointed out by @Günter, your snippet contains some errors. Here is the correct one:

```
<form role="form" #form="form" (ngSubmit)="submit(form.value)">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" ngControl="name">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" [(ngModel)]="email">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```