# Why is my form not sending properly? [(ngModel)] vs sending the form - Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a form that I am sending for a login screen.

Since I am passing in the form itself into the backend, I have since changed the implementation to stop binding to the inputs [(ngModel)]... This passes the original tests I wrote in the first place, however now the actual app implementation no longer works...

Could somebody explain what is the problem here? The code I post is merely an example for ease of understanding as my code is much more verbose.

**BEFORE**

---

**app.ts**

```
username: string;

onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
  if (form.valid) {
    // do something with this.username...

    // this.username will be set to whatever is entered in the input box as it is bound with [(ngModel)]
  }
}
```

**app.html**

```
<input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" type="text" autofocus required
             placeholder="username" [(ngModel)]="username"/>
```

**After**

---

**app.ts**

```
username: string;

onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
  this.username = form.value.username
  if (form.valid) {
    // do something with this.username...

    // this.username should now be what is passed via the form
  }
}
```

**app.html** now no longer has [(ngModel)]="username"

```
<input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" type="text" autofocus required
             placeholder="username"/>
```

Comment: What is the reason to avoid using ngModel? This is exactly what it is for... There is no automated binding to form elements in Angular, so you'll need to bind the input to the relevant property somehow. ngModel is the normal way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input need a binding. You could do it with reactive forms:

app.ts

```
import {FormControl} from "@angular/forms";

...
usernameCtrl = new FormControl();

onSubmit()
{
    if(this.usernameCtrl.valid)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

app.html

```
<input ... [formControl]="usernameCtrl" />
```

#### Edit

Difference between NgModel & NgControl: [Difference between using ng-model and ng-control in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474616/difference-between-using-ng-model-and-ng-control-in-angular2)

There they said:

> Controls are responsible to get hints about the state of the form or a specific input (valid, pristine, touched, ...). It's commonly used to display validation errors if any.

I think a better soulution than FormControl is FormGroup (If you have more than one input):

app.ts

```
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";
...
//decorator
export class SomeClass implements OnInit
{
    public reactiveForm = new FormGroup();

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

    public ngOnInit()
    {
        this.reactiveForm = this.fb.group({username: [""]});
    }

    public onSubmit()
    {
        if(this.reactiveForm.valid)
        {
            const raw = this.reactiveForm.getRawValue(); //output -> { username: "blabla"}
            // do something with raw
        }
    }
}
```

app.html

```
<form [formGroup]="reactiveForm">
    <input ... formControlName="usernameCtrl" name="usernameCtrl"/>    
    <button [disabled]="!reactiveForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: How come it needs binding though? Surely the value for username would be passed with the form itself? Why can't I just extract the value from there? The `[formControl]` method you describe is pretty much the same as using `[(ngModel)]`